# Find the $n$ such that $n$ divides $19^n - 2$ for $n>17$ .

Tags: number-theory

$19^{17} - 2 = 5480386857784802185937 = 17 \cdot 322375697516753069761$.

So $17$  divides  $19^{17} - 2$.

Find the $n$ such that  $n$  divides  $19^n - 2$  for  $n>17$ .

P.S.

I calculate $19^{n}$ mod $n$ for $n \le 10^6 $.

There aren't such number.

Comment: It seems that there is no other $n$, but I could be wrong. Perhaps it has over 1000 digits or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

546688785009341741 is a term.

I confirm this by the following.

```
# Ruby
def pow(a, m, mod)
  return 1 if m == 0
  k = pow(a, m >> 1, mod)
  k *= k
  return k % mod if m & 1 == 0
  return k * a % mod
end

n = 546688785009341741
p pow(19, n, n)
```

Output

2

Answer (score 0):

I have one way. We know by Fermat's Little Theorem,

$n |19^n -19$ for $(n,19)=1$

Now, to have $n|19^n -2$ we need $n|17$ but $n>17$, so $n$ has to be a multiple of $19$

Then try out yourself ...

Hint, if $n|19^n -2$ where $n=19.a$, we have $19^n -2=nk$ but the RHS is $0(\mod 19)$ while LHS is $-2(\mod 19)$ so, contradiction

Comment: You need $n$ prime to apply Fermat's Little Theorem.